# Why does my W7x64 laptop show 4091Mb of RAM instead of 4096Mb?

Tags: windows-7, memory

My laptop shows me only 4091 Mb of RAM instead of 4096Mb that it should. When I remove one piece of memory (it doesn not matter which one), it then shows 2046Mb.

I do not remember when it started, but when it was new, it showed the full 4096Mb. After Windows has been re-installed it starts to shows 4094Mb, and then 4091Mb.

What could the cause of the issue be?

The Nvidia 210 has separate 512 Mb (well, as it says on laptop: "4GB RAM, 512MB video" - hope if it will be shared memory it will be printed "4GB for RAM and video").

I was using many strange OS on it - like Backtrack Linux Live DVD, Kolibri OS (that is 1.44 Mb). Could it be some kind of loop of RAM-disk or evil zero-level hypervisor? 
I tried to boot the system with another HDD and even with SATA-to-CF adapter and CF card - no matter, the lack of memory stays on :( .

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your task manager?

Answer (score 13):

The BIOS needs some memory for things like ACPI tables, power management, and so on.

Comment: Source?  According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7301275/238419) the BIOS does not access anything over the 1MB mark.

Comment: Plus, if this was the case, when he removed any single stick of memory, the BIOS would still need to "claim" the same amount of memory, which it does not.

Comment: Look at the memory map on a *modern* system. I just measured on one of my machines and the BIOS reserved 3MB of NVS memory.

Answer (score 0):

The memory address range is not only used for RAM and VRAM but also for memory-mapped IO devices such as LAN cards, sound adapters and shadow regions in BIOS, etc. You can check that with device manager or resource manager

So the number is not the real RAM size but only the usable amount of memory. Older Windows doesn't know the real size and always show the usable size, but newer Windows show both